# Can Html invoke JSF action in javascript in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

In Mozila its fine. there is an issue with IE.
There is a scenario in JSF page html and css creating a popup in certain condition, having YES and NO button. on clicking YES button a java script method is calling which should call jsf action.

Issue IE : on clicking on YES, application is logging out.

**HTML in jsf :**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
                        <div id="popup">
                                <div class="content">
                                     <div id="dynamicTable">
                                          <script>
                                               addTable();
                                         </script>
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px;">    
                                   <input type = 'submit' id ='YesBtn'  value="Yes" onclick="yesFun();"/>                                        
                                    <input type = 'submit' id ='NoBtn' value="No" onclick="cancelFun();"/>  

                                </div>          
                        </div>
```

**Java script :**

```
 function yesFun(){                 
      document.getElementById('f2:confirmationButton').click(); 
 }
```

**in JSF :**

It's working fine in Mozila. Please help, I tried multiple way.

Comment: In JSF :  <h:commandButton id="confirmationButton" value="hidden" action="#{pc_MtsSysGrp.doSaveAction}" style="visibility:hidden;" />

Comment: if it's in a form you need to prevent default event or set type=button

Comment: Thanks chalietfl.this works perfectly fine.